# Rendimiento con minificado

Tags: javascript, rendimiento

tengo una duda y no encuentro una respuesta precisa en internet.
El minificado de ficheros, está claro que mejora el rendimento, y mas si estamos trabajando con ficheros alojados en un servidor, me tengo que traer esto, al pesar menos, viene mas rápido, mejora de rendimiento notable.
Pero mi duda está en la ejecución, una librería js que tengo en local, al final las variables, funciones, etc que cargo en memoria son lo mismo ¿mejora el rendimento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que podrías hacer el caso que el parser lee menos bytes al no haber espacios en blanco, saltos de línea etc...

Pero no va a ser una mejora notable de ningún tipo... el minificado como bien has dicho es principalmente para menores transferencias de red.

Comment: si, eso es lo que pienso, vamos  a ver si hay opiniones diferentes. Gracias por contestar

Comment: Hola! Esto no está considerado una buena respuesta por la comunidad, debería ser un comentario. Las respuestas tienen que ser claras y concisas, abordando y explicando el problema. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) así ayudarás mejor a los demás y ganarás más resputación!